# Method based query for this Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq

Hi All,

```
        Employee[] empCollection =
            new Employee[]{

                   new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Test1",
            Salry = "1000",
            Notes = new string[] { "A","B","C","D"}
        },

        new Employee()
        {
              Name = "Test2",
            Salry = "2000",
            Notes = new string[] { "E","F","G","H"}

          }

            };


        var data = from e in empCollection
                   from n in e.Notes
                   select new { Name = e.Name, note = n };
```

Test1:B
Test1:C
Test1:D
Test2:E
Test2:F
Test2:G
Test2:H

I would like to know the equivalent method based synatx for this query?

I tried this

```
var data = empCollection.Select(
            e =>
                e.Notes.Select(n => new
                {
                    name = e.Name,
                    note = n
                }
                )
            );
```

But i am not able to get the name and note in the foreach loop why?

Thanks.

Comment: first i have a recomendation - check out the software "linqpad" it will help you fiddle those things out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, you need to use `SelectMany` to 'flatten' your results to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var data = empCollection
    .SelectMany(e => e.Notes.Select(n => new {name = e.Name, note = n}));
```

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx#linqoverview_topic5), your original the mechanical translation done by the compiler from query to method syntax uses an overload of `SelectMany`, creating an anonymous type to pair the two items so they can be used in the projection (note this wouldn't actually compile due to the compiler-invented variable name):

```
var data = empCollection
    .SelectMany(e => e.Notes, (e, n) => new {e, n})
    .Select($1 => new { name = $1.e.Name, note = $1.n });
```

Of course, this can then be simplified and you end up somewhere in-between the compiler generated code and your original code:

```
var data = empCollection
    .SelectMany(e => e.Notes, (e, n) => new {name = e.Name, note = n});
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TsvFdD) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks. But i am not able use this code over the result collection you mentioned. foreach(var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name +":"+item.note);
            }

Comment: eqivalent method based query for this please. <br/>var data = from e in empCollection
                   from n in e.Notes
                   select new { Name = e.Name, note = n };